# What is the difference between roles and privlages

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

Would every user who uses my database have a role? Is it more administrators who will have roles, people who need access to all the tables?

Also, I am unable to offer table-level privileges to a role and offer that to a user.. it just won't work. I have to offer the privileges directly onto the user for them to work. Is that normal? Should I be able to offer table-level privileges to a role or do I have to manually offer each of my users the table level privileges?

Comment: "A user privilege is a right to execute a particular type of SQL statement, or a right to access another user's object. The types of privileges are defined by Oracle.
Roles, on the other hand, are created by users (usually administrators) and are used to group together privileges or other roles. They are a means of facilitating the granting of multiple privileges or roles to users." https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would every user who uses my database have a role?

That depends on how you (or, should I rather say, DBA) set it up.

Quite a long time ago, say until Oracle 8i, there were 2 very popular roles: `connect` and `resource` so when DBA created a new user, they simply ran

```
grant connect, resource to new_user;
```

and the `new_user` was ready to go as those roles provided most needed privileges such as `create session`, `create table` or `create view` (check documentation for more info about those [predefined roles](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76956/privs.htm#15036)).

However, it turned out that not everyone should be granted e.g. `create cluster` (which is one of `connect`'s privileges) so nowadays you should create your own roles, if you want - then grant certain privileges to those roles and, finally, grant roles to your users.

Another option is to keep .sql scripts for each of your users. That script should contain list of privileges granted to those users, separately, which means that you shouldn't granted anyone privilege they don't really need.

---

> I am unable to offer table-level privileges to a role and offer that to a user. it just won't work. I have to offer the privileges directly onto the user for them to work. Is that normal?

It *works*, but not *everywhere*. Those privileges (the ones granted via roles) won't work in **named** PL/SQL procedures (i.e. stored procedures, functions, packages). If you have to use those tables in them, yes - you have to grant privileges directly to each of those users.

As opposed to named PL/SQL procedures, privileges granted via roles will work in anonymous PL/SQL blocks or at SQL level.

If you're wondering why would you use roles at all, then, the answer is my first sentence: *it depends*.